# XSLT if expression syntax, combining more than one expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Trying to combine an if statement using `<xsl:if test="expression">` where I want to have multiple expressions together, to do order of operations such as this psuedocode:

```
if (Number != '' and (Name != '' or PreferredName != '')) {// code here}
```

Essentially I want to do this in an `<xsl:if>`:

```
<xsl:if text="Number != '' and (Name != '' or PreferredName != '')">
```

but I'm not sure of the `expression` syntax, I don't think I can do the `()` like that, as I haven't seen it anywhere. I couldn't find the expression syntax on the web easily, it may be XPath, but I'm not sure if XPath supports `()` to group expressions. I'm not an expert on XSL/XML/XSD's' so I don't know if the expression is even XPath, or what.

I'd rather not do nested `<xsl:if>` statements if possible, and want to stick with `<xsl:if>` not `<xsl:choose>`.

I'm sure this is probably a simple answer, but kind of stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just using the brackets?

Comment: It wasn't my work that I'm looking at, I'll make a quick example and report back.

Comment: Yeah, tried it out, thanks. "()"s work as expected. I assumed it would, but again, it wasn't my code, should have just tested it alone like I just did.

Comment: **Warning**: Don't use the `!=` operator in cases when any of its arguments may be a node-set -- you'll get confusing and unwanted, non-intuitive results. Learn to avoid using `!=` as much as possible. Instead use: `not(x = someValue)` .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The conditional statement `xsl:if` for starters needs an `xsl:template` or other xsl element as parent.
The syntax will become similar to the following:

```
<xsl:template>
    ... preliminary xsl statements ...
    <xsl:if test="Number != '' and (Name != '' or PreferredName != '')">
        ... further xsl statements (the code you were referring to ...
    </xsl:if>
    ... other xsl stataments ...
</xsl:template>
```

Further advise: study xslt usage, in particular templates and their application (and sort of automatic looping).